# How to give navigate view like New Facebook iPhone Apps

Tags: iphone, facebook, view

I saw the new iPhone apps and it is superb. They have nearly more than 9 sections and they have given good navigate view. They have removed tab bar controller and instead of they have given one good navigate view.

Does any have seen this new Facebook apps and knows that how can we give same navigate view for the any apps.

Answer (score 5):

The Three20 library has the 'Launcher View' class within it. It's an open source library and free for use.

http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master

This library was written by Joe Hewitt, the developer of the Facebook app and was derived from the Facebook app itself.

Comment: Can you give me class name. I tied to find but i didn't get it. TT?

Comment: TTLauncher is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The first view could (ignore the search bar and above) be a UIView with a UIPageControl below it.  In the UIView they have a number of subviews, which could be UIViews, UIIMageViews or UIButtons.  If they are UIViews or UIImageViews, then you have to handle taps yourself.

It is a pretty clean interface.

Comment: How can i give zooming animation effect when we select any button?

Comment: Yes.  You could also spin the buttons, make them invert or change colors, or pulse or... the animation options are limitless.